# security-opt with docker-api gem

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, docker, docker-api

I want to use security-opt option with docker-api gem .How can I implement it. I have found nothing about it in [docker-api](https://github.com/swipely/docker-api) documentation. Somebody please help.

Answer (score 0):

After a quick read of the documentation and [this example](https://github.com/swipely/docker-api/issues/123#issuecomment-40087785), it looks like that library simply allows you to follow the JSON structure as [is used by the Docker API](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/6213cc9d0476ee43bc92e554f4775e33c3c4d38f/docs/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.21.md#create-a-container)

For the `--security-opt` option, this means that you should pass this option as `SecurityOpt` inside `HostConfig`. I'm not a Ruby code, but probably like this;

```
container = Docker::Container.create(
  "Cmd" => ["my", "command"],
  "Image" => "someimage"
  "HostConfig" => [
      "SecurityOpt" => ["apparmor:unconfined"]
  ]
  # Other configuration as needed.
)
```

Hope this helps